# C++ dynamic array of dynamic strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory-management, dynamic

I know how to create a dynamic array of strings in C++:

```
string* array = new string[10];
```

But how do I create a dynamic array of dynamic strings in C++? I mean a dynamic array that holds `string*` objects. And how do I initialize each one of the dynamic strings?

Comment: You don't.  As you are already using `std::string` use a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: First, don't call your variable `array`, as there is already a `std::array` class in C++.  Second, `std::vector<std::string> arr(10);` does what your code is trying to do.

Comment: You want a dynamic array of pointers to `strings`? It would look like `string ** array = new string*[10];`  followed by a for loop assigning `array[index] = new string;` Be aware that there is less use for that that you might think. Odds are very good that if this is what you believe you need, you're headed in the wrong direction. Let us in on the actual goal and maybe someone can give you a better idea.

Comment: Class `std::string` is already contains a dynamic string object and `std::vector` contains a dynamic array object. So `std::vector<std::string>>` actually does what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that if you need to implement what you're asking, you should probably rethink your design. However the syntax for what you're asking is exactly correlative to the array of strings:

```
string** sillyIdea = new string*[10];
//some access examples
sillyIdea[0]= new string;
*(sillyIdea[0]) = "hello";
(*(sillyIdea[0]))[0] = 'H'; 
 sillyIdea[1]= new string;

//statement below looks like a 2d array construct but it is not, 
//just shorthand for  
// *((sillyIdea[1]) + 0)
 sillyIdea[1][0] = "world"; 
//an array of pointers can usually be treated programtcally as a
//jaggedarray(asymtrical multi-dimensional array). In other words,
// your array of string pointers can be treated like an array of one
//element string arrays, making for a cleaner syntax, but worse code.

//in int main(int argc, char** argv), argv is one such example of a jagged array.
```

the string vector suggested above will yield less heartache

Answer (score 0):

You already know that you can create an array of `string` objects with `new string[n]`.

You can expand that idea to allocate an array of objects of any<sup>†</sup> type `T`: `new T[n]`. If you wish to create an array of `string*` objects, you can simply use `new string*[n]`.

---

That said, there is hardly ever need to dynamically allocate an instance of `std::string`. And hardly ever need to manually allocate a dynamic array instead of using `std::vector`.

---

† There are some limitations. With this particular syntax, the type must be default constructible.

Answer (score -2):

Simple example :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>m;
    string** array = new string*[n];

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new string[m];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++)
    cin>>array[i][j];


    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++)
    cout<<array[i][j]<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does he mean two dimensional array? No problem

Comment: Nah. I think OP wants an array of pointers to `string`s. Can't think of a good reason why, though.